# How to convert innertext?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, window, winapp

Hello I retrieve data from webbrowser control by use getelementbyid.

**var element = webbrowser.document.getelementbyid(something);**

i have a problem is cant convert to double which can convert to string.
i want to know about convertion to be double. it's can possible?

---

i tried already but ...

Input string was not in a correct format.

What's wrong?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use value of html element.

Try this,

```
double d = double.Parse(webbrowser.document.getelementbyid(something).value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
double d;
string element = webbrowser.document.getelementbyid(something).Value;
if (Double.TryParse(element, out d))
{
    // Conversion succesful: in d you find your number
}
```

Take a look at [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the value in string form, you should use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) to parse it as a `double`, e.g.:

```
double number;

if (Double.TryParse(webbrowser.document.getelementbyid(something), out number))
{
   // ... do something useful with 'number' ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to do something like this;

```
string innerHtml = webbrowser.Document.GetElementById(something).InnerHtml;
double value;

if(Double.TryParse(innerHtml, out value))
{
    // value is now populated
};
```